# Google maps multi touch pinch and zoom (desktop) touch pc

Tags: windows, zooming, multi-touch

How can I pinch and zoom through Google maps on a windows 7 mutli-touch pc?  I am building a Google maps v3 Javascript-based app which must be touched-based.  There won't be a keyboard -- Windows 7 touchscreen pc.  In every browser I've tried, it will zoom in on the website instead of zooming in on Google maps!

Answer (score -2):

I assume you already have the answer, but for the benefit of others the solition is to install the Touch Pack from Microsoft for Windows 7. Here's the link - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/whats-the-microsoft-touch-pack-for-windows-7